# How do I replace portions of a string which have a specific format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am working on my Rails application in which I've implemented mentions using the jQuery [autocomplete](http://mydons.com/auto-complete-friends-list-like-facebook-or-google-using-input-with-jquery/)  plugin.

This is an example string containing mentions when an update is submitted:

-> Hello **Kenneth Auchenberg** its been long. Tell **Pete Lacey** I will see him tomorrow

On the server side I receive the string as:

-> Hello @[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:1) its been long. Tell @[Pete Lacey](user:6) I will see him tomorrow

After processing this string I want to get the user's name inside the bracket and the user's id after the semicolon, i.ee `kenneth Auchenberg` and his ID `1`, and replace `@[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:1)` and `@[Pete Lacey](user:6)` with a link to their profile and remove the unnecessary `@`, `[]` and `()` signs so that the resulting string can be something like

-> Hello [Kenneth Auchenberg](http://site.com/user/kenneth)  its been long. Tell [Pete Lacey](http://www.user.com/user/pete) I will see him tomorrow

So far, all I have done is only getting the user's name inside the square brackets:

```
string.scan(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)
```

Which gives me:

```
[["Kenneth Auchenberg"], ["Pete Lacey "]]
```

I know of the `gsub` and `scan` functions in Ruby but I am not able to get them to give me my desired result. I'm still a newbie in using Ruby regex. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is really handy when working out regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this implementation is clear and self documented, since you make explicit the patterns of regular expression you are interesting in:

```
s = 'Hello @[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:1) and @[Pete Lacey](user:6)!!!'

s.gsub! /@\[(?<name>[\w\s]+)\]\(user:(?<userid>\d+)\)/ do
  m = $~ # capture MatchData
  name, id = m[:name], m[:userid] # read the parsed content
  # do anything with them
  ...
  "<a href=\"/user/#{id}\">#{name}</a>" # replace by link
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "Hello @[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:1) its been long. Tell @[Pete Lacey](user:6) I will see him tomorrow"

string.scan(/@\[(.*?)\]\(user:(\d+)\)/)
```

returns:

```
[
  [
    "Kenneth Auchenberg",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "Pete Lacey",
    "6"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know how to write up the `gsub` function, then I'm pretty sure you can use the regex:

```
@\[([^\]\s]+)([^\]]+)\]\([^\)]+\)
```

And replace by:

```
[$1$2](site.com/user/$1)
```

Tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/cB0bT6)

The `\[([^\]\s]+)([^\]]+)\]` part is the name. I have put two capture groups to separate the two parts of the username to be used later in the links.

The first captures the first name and the second captures the second name. The replace then calls back the capture groups and puts them in the new string.